# What's the difference between $min/$max and $lte/$gt?

Tags: mongodb

I don't quite understand what the difference between `$min`/`$max` and `$lte`/`$gt`? I'm not sure how query modifiers differ from query operators for these methods. I understand that `$min`/`$max` is necessary for compound index bounds but does it make a difference for specifying bounds on a single index field?

Comment: $min and $max decide the min and max value of scanning in the index where as gt and lte are just range queries

Comment: So, `$min`/`$max` are better? I'm not sure if this affects performance if not end result.

Comment: Depends on what your doing?

Comment: I want to page a collection on the _id field and page another collection on number of votes.

Comment: paging on the _id field actually be best done by a $min $max since you want to query within that range of index keys, but can also be done by $gt

Comment: `$min` and `$max` also force use of an index (for the fields specified), even when another index may have made more sense.

Comment: @WiredPrairie didn't actually know that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Simple explanation:*  min max does not work without index on that field.

*Longer explanation:*
[$min](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/min/) and [$max](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/max/) are query modifiers and [$lte](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/#op._S_lte) and [$gt](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/#op._S_gt) are query operators. Query modifiers (as a name suggests) modify the behaviour of the query. But

> On the server, MongoDB treats the query and the options as a single
>   object.

This means that if you are doing `db.coll.find({}).min({a : 1});` it does not find everything and then select everything bigger bigger or equal to one. The most familiar to everyone is `sort` modifier. You can use every modifier in this way as well `db.collection.find()._addSpecial("modifierName", "options" )`

Both commands are doing similar things. The differences are subtle:
$min and $max can only search if that field has an index. Otherwise it will fail with error. Moreover, while searching it is using that index and if you want to use something else you have to tell this with [hint](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/#cursor.hint) command.

Suppose you have collection zips with the documents of the following format:

```
{
  "city" : "ACMAR",
  "loc" : [-86.51557, 33.584132],
  "pop" : 6055,
  "state" : "AL",
  "_id" : 35004
}
```

If you will do `db.zips.find().min( { pop: 5000 } )`. it will just crush with error. While doing the same with $gte will be executed just fine. If you will ensure index on this field, you can execute this command and it will use this index.

Regarding the comment about hint command. Assume you need something like this `db.zips.find({_id : 333}).min( { pop: 5000 } )` and you have index on pop. You will use it, nonetheless it would be much better to use _id index.

**So in total it is up to you to decide what is better.**

- If you have an index on the field and always want to use it - you can go with .max / .min
- If you do not have it - you have to stick with $gte / $lt.
- if you have an index but think that mongo better knows what index should it use, also go with $gte /$lt

**PS.** I do not like this commands because they are ambiguous. With one min the boundary is inclusive, with max it is exclusive and I do not know how to remember it.

Comment: min and max does actually effect where the find criteria actually looks unlike $gt and lt

Comment: can you please rephrase you comment, because I can not understand it :-)

Comment: Min and max have the ability to define the lower limit of the index, or rather the lower bounds whereas range operators do not

Comment: If `$min`/`$max` bound the cursor at the index level, when would you possibly want to use `$lte`/`$gt`? I'm still not understanding why these operators co-exist even though I understand what the specific differences among them are with respect to indexing.

Comment: @PaulKonova A good reason is to change how the find actually works, there are a number of pagination cases where $gt and lt don't work and so limiting the actual scan of the index does, there are other scenarios as well